# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function _inherits in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In react-native.I will create a simple app and also a web app.
React-native application output the error show in image.

> Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBq32.png)

My code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component() {
 render(){
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text>Hello World</Text>

     </View>
   );
 }
}
export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: '#fff',
   alignItems: 'center',
   justifyContent: 'center',
 },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the parenthesis on the class definition.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
 render(){
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text>Hello World</Text>

     </View>
   );
 }
}
export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   flex: 1,
   backgroundColor: '#fff',
   alignItems: 'center',
   justifyContent: 'center',
 },
});
```